# FitNesse / FitSharp - Read columns of ColumnFixture dynamically

Tags: c#, testing, fitnesse, fitsharp

I am using the FitNesse / FitSharp (c#) for testing purposes.

I can create normal fixture like ColumnFixtures, RowFixtures, DoFixtures etc. but not I am looking for a way to read columns and bind them dynamically.

The reason for this is, I still already have a huge amount of Pojo objects in my own library and don't want to repeat all class members again. Therefor i am searching for a way to handle column dynamically.

e.g.

```
!|Create| pojoType | record | pojoName |
 |Name  | LastName | Address| Misc     |
 | a    | b        | c      | d        |


public class DynamicHandling : DoFixture () {
   public void CreateRecord(string type, string name) {
      var clazz = GetClazzOfType();

      var headers = GetHeadersOfColumn();
      var values = GetValuesOfColumn();

      var pojo = DoBindingAndAssignValues(headers, rows, clazz);

      // ... Continue with whatever e.g.  ...

      var name = pojo.Name;
      var lastName = pojo.LastName;
      var address = pojo.Address;

      address.split(';') ... 
   }
}
```

Any idea ?

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do. Are you creating an instance of pojoType and assigning properties Name = a or are the columns constructor parameters? What is pojoName? And what would you do with pojo when it's created?

Comment: The main point of my question is. How could I read the entire column in FitNesse and create the binding by myself. 

Creating an instance for my pojo etc. would be the next step, but isn't the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the source code for the Compute fixture (https://fitsharp.github.io/Fit/ComputeFixture.html) and see if it helps.

You can write a fixture that processes cells dynamically like this:

```
public class MyFixture: Interpreter {
  public void Interpret(CellProcessor processor, Tree<Cell> table) {
    new Traverse<Cell>()
      .Rows.Header(row => FunctionThatDoesSomethingWithTheHeaderRow(row))
      .Rows.Rest(row => FunctionThatDoesSomethingWithEachSubsequentRow(row))
      .VisitTable(table);
  }
  ...
}
```

There's other sets of rows you can traverse - check out the Traverse source code.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for.